# how to create low poly cliff

Tags: modeling, polycount

I want to create cliff with path to make roads as low poly like in below image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, really.
First, you create two cubes, one slightly smaller than the other.

[image]

The select the bigger one of them and in edit mode add loop cuts vertically.
Between 24-48 loops should be enough.
[image]

Then select one of the edge loops press 'O' to activate proportional editing and then select random falloff.

[image]

Switch to top view, click on the respective axis manipulator and drag forward.

[image]

Then add 2 horizontal edge loops and repeat the same process with each of the loops. (Adjust it forward and backward as you see fit)
[image]

**NOTE :** Switch between random falloff and smooth falloff if you feel the edges are too jagged.

Then exit edit mode and move the "rough-edged" cube such that it overlaps the smaller cube.
[image]

Next, select the smaller cube and and add the Boolean Modifier and set the operation to "Difference", also make sure the Solver is set to "Bmesh" else the poly-flow may not be even and then press "Apply".
[image]
[image]

You may delete the bigger cube if you have no further use of it. Now, in edit mode, select all the faces you want to make a ledge or road and press "E" to extrude. Extrude till where you want it.
[image]

Hope this is the answer you were looking for. :)